# Dynamic select doesn't get results

Tags: sql, oracle, select, dynamic, plsql

I'm trying to execute dynamic select in loop but i don't get any results. I would like to make it work like normal select.

```
create or replace type proc_args as varray(20) of varchar2(50);
/

create or replace procedure proc_show_tab(args proc_args)
is
 id_kursora integer;
 wart integer;
 polecenie varchar2(30);

  begin
    for i in 1..args.count loop
      polecenie := 'SELECT * FROM '||args(i);
      execute immediate polecenie;        
    end loop;
  end;
/

show error;

declare
  args2 proc_args;
begin
  args2 := proc_args();
  args2.extend(2);
  args2(1) := 'osrodek';
  args2(2) := 'trasa';

  proc_show_tab(args2);
end;
/
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't get any results. Your current code does the select and then nothing else.

Comment: Because in output i get only:
`TYPE proc_args compiled
PROCEDURE proc_poka_tabele compiled
No Errors.
anonymous block completed`

Comment: It's not going to output the results by itself. You have to, for instance, insert them into a table or `dmbs_output.put_line` etc.

Answer (score 5):

PL/SQL is not like T-SQL in how it returns data to the executing client. 
A SQL SELECT statement is being executed twice in your code, but does not return the results back to anything - to return data to a client, you need to explicitly return a REF CURSOR (and the client needs to know that you are) or use DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line or something similar to display your results in the "output." When you get "anonymous block completed" that means that your block completed without errors.

How to return the results will vary depending on what you are trying to accomplish.